# How to move to next ansible task as bootstrap cluster script runs forever?

Tags: ansible, nodes, etcd

My ansible task to bootstrap a 5 cluster node works, but how to configure my task to continue executing the rest of tasks in the playbook, as it is hanged by bootstrapping the nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you do not need to wait on the task to complete, you may run the task asynchronously by specifying a poll value of 0:

please check example. first task is a sleep 60 command, you will notice ansible moved on to next task while sleep command is still executing on the host.

```
[root@optima-ansible ILIAS]# cat testt.yml 
---
- name: test play
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false
  become: yes
  vars:

  tasks:
  - name: simulate long running op (15 sec), wait for up to 45 sec, poll every 5 sec
    command: /bin/sleep 60
    async: 45
    poll: 0

  - debug:
      msg: "moving on"
[root@optima-ansible ILIAS]# ansible-playbook testt.yml 

PLAY [test play] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [simulate long running op (15 sec), wait for up to 45 sec, poll every 5 sec] **************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [debug] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "moving on"
}

PLAY RECAP *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0   

[root@optima-ansible ILIAS]# ps -ef | grep sleep
root     10004 10003  0 19:30 ?        00:00:00 /bin/sleep 60
root     10010  5697  0 19:30 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto sleep
[root@optima-ansible ILIAS]#
```